# Asynchronous recursive functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, web-audio-api

I am trying to stream mp3 data from my server to the client side. I am doing this using Ajax. The server sends 50 kilobytes per request. I wrote two functions: one that gets the mp3 data and one that plays them. The first function takes the 50 kilobytes, decodes them and stores the decoded data in an array then it calls itself recursively. The second function starts playing as soon as the first element in the array is filled with data. The problem is that this works for the first 50kilobytes only then it fails. What I want to do  is keep my get_buffer function running until the server tells it no more data to send, and keep my play() function playing data until there is no more elements in the array.

Here is my two functions:

```
function buffer_seg() {
    // starts a new request
    buff_req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Request attributes
    var method = 'GET';
    var url = '/buffer.php?request=buffer&offset=' + offset;
    var async = true;

    // set attributes
    buff_req.open(method, url, async);
    buff_req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // keeps loading until something is recieved
    if (!loaded) {
        change_icon();
        buffering = true;

    }


    buff_req.onload = function() {
        segment = buff_req.response;

        // if the whole file was already buffered
        if (segment.byteLength == 4) {
            return true;
        } else if (segment.byteLength == 3) {
            return false;
        }
        // sets the new offset
        if (offset == -1) {
            offset = BUFFER_SIZE;
        } else {
            offset += BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
        //decodes mp3 data and adds it to the array
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(segment, function(decoded) {
            buffer.push(decoded);
            debugger;
            if (index == 0) {
                play();
            }

        });


    }
    buff_req.send();
    buff_seg();
}
```

Second function:

```
function play() {

    // checks if the end of buffer has been reached
    if (index == buffer.length) {
        loaded = false;
        change_icon();
        if (buffer_seg == false) {
            stop();
            change_icon();
            return false;
        }
    }
    loaded = true;
    change_icon();

    // new buffer source
    var src = audioContext.createBufferSource();

    src.buffer = buffer[index++];

    // connects 
    src.connect(audioContext.destination);

    src.start(time);
    time += src.buffer.duration;
    src.onended = function() {
        src.disconnect(audioContext.destination);
        play();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call to `buffer_seg` is in the main body of `buffer_seg`, not in the callback, so it happens immediately - not, as you seem to intend, after a response is received.  Second, this also means that the recursive call is unconditional when it should be based on whether the previous response indicated more data would be available.  If this isn't just crashing your browser, I'm not sure why.  It also means that chunks of streamed audio could be pushed into the buffer out of order.

So to start I'd look at moving the recursive call to the end of the `onload` handler, after the check for end of stream.

In the 2nd function, what do you intend `if (buffer_seg == false)` to do?  This condition will never be met.  Are you thinking this is a way to see the last return value from `buffer_seg`?  That's not how it works.  Perhaps you should have a variable that both functions can see, which `buffer_seg` can set and `play` can test, or something like that.

Comment: "offset" variable tells the server starting which byte should the server sent the mp3 audio. So the server replies with "done" if the offset is sent to the end of file or after the end of file. I check if the size of the arraybuffer is equals to 4 than it must be "done". It returns false then. Sorry it's my bad, it should be (buffer_seg() == false). it's calling the buffer_seg() function when it reaches the end of the array to see if buffer_seg will buffer new data or returns false indicating the EOF. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Yes, I know what you intend offset to do.  I'm not sure why you're pointing this out; it doesn't change that responses can come back out of order as you've written your code.  Also, `(buffer_seg() == false)` won't work any better as the call to `buffer_seg` will never return.  In any case since you have `buffer_seg` calling itself there is no point having `play` call it also.

Comment: Yeah I agree on your points, I can see how this can cause the script not to run correctly and I even corrected some of this problems already. But do you have any suggestions on how I might be able to write a function that keeps streaming data in the background and storing them in an array and another function that reads the array and stores it. Or any idea how can I buffer mp3 binary data and play it before the whole buffering is done ?